# d3.csv: using specific row data to use in a for loop argument

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I have been searching for a while on ways to use the d3.csv function to gather data from a CSV, and return a row so that I could use it in a 'for loop' in a different function to set how many times the for loop should run.

Below is the main layout of my code showing the two functions in question.

With my 'createLights function' I wanted it to call the 'getData' function to return a specific row in order for the 'lightPol' variable in the 'createLights' function to run a for loop to generate random SVG squares.

However, due to the asynchronicity of javascript and d3, I haven't been able to do this. I'm a beginner with d3 so don't really understand certain features of it.

```js
<...>

    function createLights(tempHeight) {


      var lightPol = getData(1);;
      console.log(lightPol); //debug data to be retuend

      for (m = 0; m < lightPol; m++) { //amount egenrated
        tempHeight = tempHeight * 1.5;
        var window_height = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 0; //pos rand
        var window_space = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) + 10; //pos rand
        window_space = window_space + i;
        var shape1 = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "rect"); //to create a circle/rct 
//attributes
        document.getElementById("mysvg2").appendChild(shape1);

      }
    }

    function getData(pollution) {
      //console.log(pollution);//see if polution varible read right
      var dataset = [];

      d3.csv("py/Resources.csv", function(data) {

        dataset = data.map(function(d) {
          return +d.value;
        });
        //reutrn dataset[pollution]''
      });

      return 5; //placeholder of function, the d3 should generate a number and return it.


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` in the callback of `d3.csv("py/Resources.scv")` would hold everything that you need. I do not know your specific structure of code but you can go the simple way first of doing drawing and everything inside that callback

WHich mean CreateLight should be inside of GetData

Comment: Okay, I have managed to merge the two functions, but as I'm new to D3, I don't seem to recall how to create SVG squares using D3 when I have existing 'svg-containers'

Comment: That one should be another question, but the main point of it that you would give d3 data and append a rec to a svg, for example. May be try this link: https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-basic-shapes-and-d3js

Comment: Thanks for the link! I was able to create the SVGs now, thank you for the help!